# svn merge error "can't get text contents of a directory"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I try to merge changes from one revision in trunk to the branch. I use the option "Merge a range of revisions" in Tortoise SVN. I get following error. Do you have any clue what is wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge a directory (`http://192.168.1.3/svn/elma/sq/elmasq/trunk`) into a file (`D:/Projects/Elma_Optimization_Temp/c_parcmd.cpp`), hence the error `Can't get text contents of a directory`.

On the `Merge revision range` dialogue (your second attached screenshot), try providing `http://192.168.1.3/svn/elma/sq/elmasq/trunk/c_parcmd.cpp` (or wherever that file is located in the repo trunk) as the `URL to merge from` (the first text field on that dialogue).